# glitches with tables and divs (position: absolute) in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, visual-glitch

I have built a calendar for a web app, similar to the [FixedHeaderTable jQuery plugin](http://fixedheadertable.com/).
For the grids I use a structure like `<div style="position:absolute; overflow:scroll"><tables/></div>` and set the div's `scrollTop`.

Sometimes scrolling produces a glitch:
[image: the glitch]

This happens (at least) with OSX 10.6.8 and Firefox 25, and I'm aware that this is a narrow target group and hard to reproduce, but I'm still interested in possible causes for this type of glitch, and, of course, possible solutions (force a redraw?).

So far I know that it goes away if I don't use `position: absolute` for the `div`...

Bonus: In the table cells I have boxes, built like so:

```html
<td>
    <div style="position:relative">
        <div style="position:absolute; width:100px; height:100px; z-index:10" />
    </div>
</td>
```

whose background color and borders disappear when they're partially scrolled out of view:
[image]
(monique is transparent...)

Now, omitting the inner `div`s `z-index` fixes this issue, BUT not omitting it fixes the first issue.

Ok, sorry that this is so narrow, but maybe somebody has seen something similar before.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `position:relative;` to the `body`.

That will fix it.

Comment: thanks, I'll check&report tomorrow when I get access to the affected machine

Comment: that didn't fix it. would you care to explain why it should have? (so i know where to start with this thing)

Comment: In that case, you can make a jsFiddle or provide a live demo link with this issue so that it can be debugged further. - @kubi

Comment: I would have thrown together a demo/fiddle if the affected system/browser setup had been more accessible to me (and others). That's why I asked for the idea behind your idea... Anyhow, I worked around the issue by giving the table a `background-color`, and getting rid of almost all `z-index`es.